# Dúvida com SQL injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um método interno que e chamado com base em outra consulta, ele está desta forma a baixo. Gostaria de saber se isso seria um erro "string.Format", se seria possível enviar um SQL injection?

```
public BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity ProdutoDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
{
    var strQuery = "";
    strQuery += " Usp_Site_BuscaProdutosDermaClub";
    strQuery += string.Format(" @codigoproduto = '{0}' ", codigoproduto);

    using (contexto = new Contexto())
    {
        var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
        return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

```
public SqlDataReader ExecutaComandoComRetorno(string strQuery)
{
    var cmdComando = new SqlCommand(strQuery, minhaConexao);
    return cmdComando.ExecuteReader();
}
```

No banco de dados a procedure tem uma variável @codigoproduto char(20), se for um erro qual a melhor correção?

Comment: É uma `StoredProcedure`? porque passa o valor assim se for `StoredProcedure` se existe a maneira ideal e correta? o que tem dentro `ExecutaComandoComRetorno` ele trata os dados?

Comment: ajustei a pergunta

Comment: Sim tem problemas seu código no quesito segurança e outros...

Comment: Complementando o que já foi dito: Alem de usar Parameters definindo sua consulta de forma "imutável" em sua construção e utilização, valide as entradas e saídas, seguindo a ideia de "Least privilege", dando ao usuário apenas o necessário par aquele contexto. Um exemplo é um campo que tem a finalidade de receber apenas caracteres literais, por que receber caracteres especiais? Ou ate mesmo se precisar, valide possíveis entradas maliciosas. - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Least_privilege

Answer (score 5):

**SIM!** Usar concatenação de string é a principal forma de criar oportunidade de sobre um *SQL Injection*. Não importa se por concatenação explícita - `"a" + "b"` - com extensões - `string.Format("{0}", "a")` - ou por interpolação - `$"{a}"`.

Para prevenir isso é bem simples, mas usar SqlParameters, e usar o SqlCommand com StorageProcedure da forma correta:

```
public ProdutoEntity TrazProdutoPorCodigo(string codigoProduto)
{
    using (var db = new Contexto())
    {
        var cmd = db.CreateCommand();

        // Instruir seu command que irá executar uma SP.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StorageProcedure;
        cmd.Command = "Usp_Site_BuscaProdutosDermaClub";

        // Aqui é onde se evita SQL Injection 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("codigoproduto", codigoProduto));

        // Executar a consulta
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(dr).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**PS**: Da uma lida sobre [ORM Dapper](https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/). Acredito que irá te ajudar bastante.